# how to implement a new line

Tags: assembly, x86

i'm working in text mode 80x25 and am expecting some string of characters terminated by 0 to print (no CRLF before). how can I then jump to the next line? what i actualy need is aligning the es:edi (0:b8000) offset to next multiplier of 160, but i have no idea how to do it somehow smart. if you have already done this or have any idea please share it with me or give me a hint. i don't want any interrupts and solutions without division are prefered. thx stu

Comment: I'm not really an assembly programmer, but couldn't you add 160 to the offset, compute the remainder using `DIV` and subtract it from the offset?

Comment: yea i thought about that as an option, but that's at least 2 registers overwritten and i'm kinda short on them, but yea if there is no bitsmashing way to achieve it i'll do it this way

Comment: Another approach is to simply use a 2000 byte lookup table, offset -> next 160-multiple.

Comment: it has to fit into bootloader :) what i used before was routine like this L1: mov edi,0xb8000+160 add word [L+1],160 which doesnt work if you print a whole line..

Comment: why wouldnt you use an interrupt?

Comment: anti-viruses don't like it. nah just kidding. because i'm supposed to test all graphical modes with VBE and in the description, the write functions are guaranteed for tty mode only, so i can rely only on what has been given by standard specification. but don't worry the way with counting printed characters seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

As Anders said, I'd do something like:

```
nextlineoffset = offset + (160 - ((offset + 160) mod 160))
```

That is,

1. Add a line to offset
2. Subtract away the extra offset

It uses one division, but does away the need of a multiplication.

Comment: i was rather thinking if i could have a use of the fact that 160 is 128 + 32 which always are the two same bits, so somehow mask them out, then if they're set/cleared leave them/zero them and everything to the right, then add 160.

Answer (score 0):

How about a `switch`-like construction? If you'r only interested in 160 character chunks on an 80x25 screen there are only thirteen cases to account for, and that should be a manageable (and renderable) sequence of `CMP` and conditional jumps.

Comment: the idea is nice, unfortunately those are not 160 character chunks the video ram is filled with, but color-character couples so it's 25 cases and that's 25*(5+5+2) (5 for cmp, 5 for mov and 2 for branch jump) bytes and i only get 512 bytes space in bootloader and stil got job to do. the division way would be like 14 bytes on each line break for what i tried.

Comment: i think in the end counting the characters printed and checking whether it has already been 80 is the most memory effective. that compare is not nice but it's constantly 9 bytes which is kinda what i wanted.